# What are the sampling distributions underlying a product of gaussian variables (moderated effect)?

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, t-distribution

I'm trying for a while now to understand the differential power of main effects (two random variables) and moderated effects (the product of these two random variables). At this point, I'm mostly interested in Gaussian. I'm working with a model like :
\begin{equation}
y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x+\beta_2 z+\beta_3 xz+\epsilon_y
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \begin{bmatrix}\mu_X \\ \mu_Z \end{bmatrix} ,\,\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) \end{equation}
I'm specifically looking for the sampling distribution of $\beta_3$ compared to regression coefficients (like $\beta_1$). Acknowledging that $t$-distributions should be used to test their power, I have found that there are many differences. Because $t$ is a normal ($\mathcal{N}$) divided by $\sqrt{\chi^2/n}$, I investigated in this direction, and found out these differences.

First, the normal distribution of $\beta_3$ as slightly different standard deviation than $\beta_1$, i.e., $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{(n-8)(1+\rho^2)}}$ (or something very similar) instead of $\sqrt{ \frac{ \sigma^2}{n}}$.

Second, the expected $\chi^2$ seems to be a lognormal instead. It has heavier tails and is more skewed. I have not found how to derive the parameters of the log normal yet, but I've come across some approximations.

Finally, the $t$-distribution of $\beta_3$ does not behave as expected. It has a slightly underestimated noncentral parameters ($\delta$) and, more importantly, its variance is not the expected $v/(v-2)(1+\delta^2)-\mu_1^2$, $v$ being the degree of freedom and $\mu_1$ is its first moment, except when $\delta=0$. Using the previous points and this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/507175/102655), I have tried to fit the function:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y}\int_0^\infty \exp\{ -[zy-\mu_x]^2/2\sigma_x^2-[\log(y)-\mu_y]^2/2\sigma_y^2\}~\text dy$

where $Z$ is the normal, $Y$ the lognormal, and dividing $\mu_y$ and $\sigma_y$ by 2, because I am interested in the square root of the lognormal (see this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531094/what-is-the-pdf-of-a-normal-distribution-divided-by-the-square-root-of-a-log-nor)).
However, this pdf does not yield "perfect" results (see last figure).

My questions are :

1. Is there a way to analytically derived the parameters of the
   lognormal based on the informations in the models?
2. What would be the function to fit the "$t$-distribution" of $\beta_3$ or how to correct the graphic presentation, or is it normal to be that way, or is the distribution actually a skewed generalized $t$ distribution?

This problems is very important to me and any help would be appreciated. Thank you,

---

As a supplement, this is an example of code on what I'm trying to achieve.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(fitdistrplus)
cores = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(cores[1]-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# The function in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/507175/102655
# Z = normal
# X = lognormal
f = function(z,x,mz,mx,sz,sx) {
  exp(- (z * x - mz)^2/(2 * sz ^ 2)-(log(x) - mx) ^ 2 / (2 * sx ^ 2))
}
norm_lognorm = function(z,mz,mx,sz,sx){
  1/(2*pi*sz*sx) * integrate(f = f, lower=0, upper=Inf, 
                             z = z, mz = mz, mx = mx, sz = sz, sx = sx,
                             rel.tol=.Machine$double.eps^.5)$value
}

# Parameters
reps = 100000 # number of replication
n = 50        # sample size
b = .50       # the parameters of interest (beta_3)
rho = .5      # correlation between main effects

txz = foreach(l = 1:reps, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  x = rnorm(n)
  z = rho * x + sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2) * rnorm(n)
  e = rnorm(n)
  y1 = b * x * z + sqrt(1 - b ^ 2*(1 + rho ^ 2)) * e
  txz = summary(lm(y1 ~ x * z))$coefficient[4,1:3]
  w = rnorm(n)
  y2 = w * b +  sqrt(1 - b ^ 2) * e
  tw = summary(lm(y2 ~ x + z + w))$coefficient[4,1:3]
  txz = c(txz, tw)
}
# txz contains estimate of xz, standard error of xz, t-value or xz, ...
# estimate of w, standard error of w, t-value of w.
# xz is the product of two random gaussian; w is a single gaussian variable to compare

Beta = matrix(c(0,0,b))
Sw   = matrix(c(1,rho,0,rho,1,0,0,0,1),3,3)
Sxz  = matrix(c(1,rho,0,rho,1,0,0,0,1 + rho^2),3,3)

# R2 for both models
R2w  = c(t(Beta)%*%Sw%*%Beta)
R2xz = c(t(Beta)%*%Sxz%*%Beta)

# estimation of the parameters of the lognormal
est = summary(fitdist(txz[2,]^2, distr = "lnorm", method = "mle"))$estimate
# Would like to know them a priori, even though I have found approximation
sx = est[2] #
mx = est[1] #

# parameters for the normal 
mz = b
sz = sqrt(1 - R2xz) / (sqrt((n - 8)*(1 + rho^2)))

# graph
par(mfcol = c(3,1), mai = c(.25, .25, .25, .25),oma = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
# blue is for xz and red if for w
hxz = hist(txz[1,], plot=FALSE, breaks=50) # hist of estimates of xz, blue
hw  = hist(txz[4,], plot=FALSE, breaks=50) # hist of estimates of w, ref

m = c(min(hxz$breaks, hw$breaks), max(hxz$breaks, hw$breaks)) # min and max of x-axis
plot(hxz, freq=FALSE, main=NULL, 
     ylim = (c(0,max(hxz$density,hw$density))), 
     xlim = m,
     col=rgb(0,0,1,.1))
plot(hw, freq=FALSE, add=TRUE, col = rgb(1,0,0,.1))

xabs = seq(m[1], m[2], by=sum(abs(m))/10000)
lines(xabs, dnorm(xabs, mean = b,  sd = sqrt(1-R2w) / (sqrt(n))), col = "red",lty=1)
lines(xabs, dnorm(xabs, mean = mz, sd = sz), col="blue", lty=1)
legend("topright", legend = ("\u03b2"), box.lty = 0, text.font = 3, bg = "transparent")

hxz = hist(txz[2,]^2, plot=FALSE, breaks=75) # hist of variances of est. of xz, blue
hw  = hist(txz[5,]^2, plot=FALSE, breaks=50) # hist of variances of est. of w, red

m = c(min(hxz$breaks,hw$breaks), max(hxz$breaks,hw$breaks))
plot(hxz, freq=FALSE, main=NULL, 
     ylim = (c(0,max(hxz$density,hw$density))),
     xlim = m,
     col = rgb(0,0,1,.1))
plot(hw, freq = FALSE, add = TRUE, col = rgb(1,0,0,.1))

abx = seq(m[1], m[2], by = sum(abs(m))/10000)
y = dchisq((abx)*(n-4)*(n-1)/(1-R2w), df=(n-4))
lines(abx, y*(n-4)*(n-1)/(1-R2w), lty=1, col="red")
y = dlnorm(abx, meanlog = mx, sdlog = sx)
lines(abx, y, lty=1, col="blue")
legend("topright", legend = ("var(\u03b2)"), box.lty = 0, text.font = 3, bg = "transparent")

hxz= hist(txz[3,], plot=FALSE, breaks=50) # hist of t values of est. of xz, blue
hw = hist(txz[6,], plot=FALSE, breaks=75) # hist of t values of est. of w, red

m = c(min(hxz$breaks,hw$breaks), max(hxz$breaks,hw$breaks))
plot(hxz, freq=FALSE, main=NULL, 
     ylim = c(0, max(hxz$density,hw$density)), 
     xlim = m, 
     col = rgb(0,0,1,.1))
plot(hw, freq = FALSE, add = TRUE, col = rgb(1,0,0,.1))

abx = seq(m[1], m[2], by = sum(abs(m))/10000)
yy = dt(abx, ncp = b*sqrt(n-4)/sqrt(1-R2w), df = n-2)
lines(abx, yy, col = "red")
yy = apply(as.matrix(abx), MARGIN=1, 
           FUN = norm_lognorm, 
           mz = mz, mx = mx/2, sz = sz, sx = sx/2)
lines(abx, yy, col="blue")
legend("topright", legend = ("t"), box.lty = 0, text.font = 3, bg = "transparent")
```

[image]

The blue is related to $\beta_3$ and the red to $\beta_1$. The simulation use $n=50, \rho=.5, \beta_1=\beta_3=.5$ (both $\beta$ are used in different data sets). I am confident for the results in red histograms and red lines, but not necessarily for the blue ones.

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: That code is ugly. You could make it easier to read by explaining what $b$ is, by replacing the repeated stuff with functions of $ha$ and $hb$, and by adding some spaces (eg as recommended at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html).

Comment: Thank for the input, I have updated my code. I hope it is clearer and cleaner!

Comment: That's better, but the definition of *norm_lognorm* is still hard to read, many individual lines still can only be read with left-right scrolling, and the code for the graphics still has a lot of repetition -- which can respectively be improved by using *dnorm*, more line breaks, and more functions. With clean code, there might be a clean answer; as it stands now, it's likely that some simple error is obscured by the mess, just like the typo in "stackexchxznge".

Comment: Hope it is better!

Comment: You say you are interested in the sampling distribution of $\beta_3$, but your model does not specify a distribution for this parameter.  Do you mean that you want the sampling distribution of the OLS *estimator* for this parameter, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Hi @Ben! Yes, I think I am looking at the sampling distribution of the OLS estimator.

Comment: Anyone has an idea or some references that could help on this topic?

Comment: I think you should start off considering $x$ and $z$ as fixed instead of random. This is the standard assumption in OLS. If this is not the case, there's little theory to go by, such as those concerning the distribution of the t-statistic. i.e. you can't expect anything to have a t distribution. Similarly with the standard error, if you integrate over the distribution of x and z, it's not (scaled) $X^2$ any more.

Comment: If you assume fixed $x$ and $z$, then the distribution of the regression coefficients should be non-central t. You can then derive the marginal distribution over random $x$ and $z$ by integrating over these vectors, although this itself is not trivial, since $xz$ is not normal.

Comment: @TimMak any recommandations (lectures or else) to help me tackle the problems. Sorry for the delay, I missed the notifications.

Comment: I suppose you can start off by reading any text on online resources on Ordinary Least Squares (OLS). You should aim to understand the matrix algebra derivation for the estimator and its variance. Also in your simulation, you shouldn't average over random x and z.